# Datepicker (month and year) not working inside fancybox

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker, fancybox-3

I am having a problem with my fancybox 3 and jquery ui datepicker.
if I place the datepicker outside the fancybox.. the dropdown for months and years are working.. but when I place it inside fancybox. the dropdown is not being triggered. any idea what is happening?

```
$("#Date_To").datepicker({changeMonth: true,changeYear: true});
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9lvV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling focusing, something like this:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
    autoFocus : false,
    trapFocus : false,
    touch     : false,
    beforeClose : function() {
        $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "hide" );
    }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/QqLXaz

Answer (score 0):

I tried using modal and found a solution. is there any way I can covert this code for fancybox?

var enforceModalFocusFn = $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus;

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};

$confModal.on('hidden', function() {
    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enfor